# Wix: one of my executables is still running even after uninstall. How do I fix it?

Tags: wix

I have this executable for the system tray icon project and was able to install and trigger it using CustomAction element in WIX:

```
<CustomAction Id="CustomActionID"
              FileKey="mySystemTrayIconEXE"
              ExeCommand=""
              Execute="deferred"
              Return="asyncNoWait">NOT REMOVE</CustomAction>
```

However, after I uninstall the application "mySystemTrayIcon.exe" is still running.  How do I make it stop?  I've searched for the answer but had no luck.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can use another custom action.

Basically, your tray application should have a trigger for stopping itself (a mutex, an event, a command line option etc.). During uninstall you can use a custom action to execute that trigger.

Another solution would be to create a custom action which kills your application process. But this is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to impliment one of the following:

- A way of telling your background application to exit cleanly
- A custom action to kill your background application (e.g. using TASKKILL.EXE)
- Force (or request) a reboot at the end of installation (and let the OS kill the app)